# Keep getting generic ip on dynamic server

Tags: ethernet, anti-virus, ip-address, dynamic-ip, bitdefender

So I've connected to my university's ethernet to get fast internet speeds rather than wifi. They use dynamic IP assignment but I keep getting assigned a generic IP address, and thus no connection. It is supposed to be a 69.56.###.### ip but I get 192.168.###.###. I think it is bitdefender but I haven't found a setting do disable or enable it. Pls help classes start in 3 days.

Comment: More than likely your school set up NAT to serve more students. So it appears from the IP addressing.

Comment: It is unlikely the address is “supposed to be” 69.56.x.x. And far more likely the address is supposed to be 192.168.x.x. The former is a public IP address unlikely to be handed out to internal devices. The latter is a private IP address which would be the overwhelming preference in this scenario. I understand your internet isn’t working, but you’re not asking the right questions or looking in the right place. Find a good tech friend who can help or contact the help desk.